# Mailgun's server got blacklisted; my outgoing mail is bouncing. No support. How to rotate IP?

Tags: mailgun, blacklist

Anyone know how to get Mailgun's attention when they have a blacklisted IP?  All my email is bouncing and there is no way to get support (for days) unless you get a very expensive plan with them.

I went to the "IPs" section of the Mailgun admin, but I am not allowed to remove the one (blacklisted) IP associated with my domain.

Sure wish I had gone with the competition at the moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @mustaccio reliably sending mail is an important part of my job in coding.  For people working with Mailgun, I am hoping someone has a way to get them to rotate a bad IP.  How is that not relevant to the work programmers do?